# HRESULT:0x80040154 for registered COM object

Tags: com, atl

I have some probles with call COM object.

```
szProgID = Imctrl.Section
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(szProgID, &clsid);
```

After execution, hr = S_OK, clsid = "CLSID_Section Class". 
But when i try create an object, CoCreateInstance returned error : "Class not Registered". Although "Imctrl.Section" exist in registry.

```
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(clsid, pUnkOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(T), (void**)&p);
```

Same error for other clases from this dll.

Comment: Maybe a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? The COM server and the COM client must use the same bitness (in general)

Comment: `Imctrl.Section` in registry only maps to CLSID, then CLSID maps to actual server implemetnation, and then it has to exist at all. All in all, it's either a problem on your end trying to instantiate a wrong thing, or the server is not just registered/available (including 32/64 probable cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to 32-bit vs. 64-bit. 
Using the utility software "**depends.exe**" I found this DLL dependencies with some third-party DLL, which did not allow to access the object.